# Problems with kivy app after transform .py to .exe or .apk

Tags: kivy, pyinstaller, kivymd, buildozer, auto-py-to-exe

Problems with kivy app after transform .py to .exe or .apk

I'm creating an app so a worker can download pdf with their info in pdf format. I'm using Google drive API and Google sheets API with Google cloud and JSON files, so I have a main.py with my main code, a .kv file, a yaml file and JSON files which are necessary to connect to my drive. In vs code my app runs ok, and no problem, but when I'm trying to transform it to an .exe using pyinstaller or an apk using buildozer, when I execute the app, it does nothing.

here's my main.py file

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(15000)  


import re , os
from itertools import cycle
from pathlib import Path

import gspread
import kivy
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from pydrive2.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive2.drive import GoogleDrive


kivy.require('1.9.0') #kivy version required

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from pydrive2.drive import GoogleDrive
from pydrive2.auth import GoogleAuth
import gspread 

sa = gspread.service_account()
sh = sa.open("Liquidaciones")
wks = sh.worksheet("liquidaciones1")
directory_credentials = 'credentials.json'
global_rut = 0



    
class LoginScreen(Screen):
    input_rut_log = ObjectProperty()
    input_pass = ObjectProperty()
   
    def on_pre_enter(self):
        Window.size = (350, 500)  

    def pass_on(self):

        @staticmethod
        def validationRut(rut):
            re.sub("[^0-9]", "", rut)
            aux = rut[:-1]
            dv = rut[-1:]
        
            reverse = map(int, reversed(str(aux)))
            factors = cycle(range(2,8))
            s = sum(d * f for d, f in zip(reverse,factors))
            res = (-s)%11
            
            if str(res) == dv:
                return True
            elif dv=="K" and res==10:
                return True
            else:
                return False
                    
        @staticmethod    
        def show_popup_rut():
            popupWindow = Popup(title="¡invalid pass or rut!", size_hint=(None,None),size=(300,50)) 
            popupWindow.open()
        
        rut = self.input_rut_log.text
        pass_in = self.input_pass.text
        global global_rut
        global_rut = rut
        counter = 0

        rut = re.sub("[^0-9]", "", rut)
        cell_one = wks.find(rut, in_column=1)
        if cell_one is not None:
            counter = wks.cell(cell_one.row, 4).value
            pass_org = wks.cell(cell_one.row, 3).value
            if pass_in!=pass_org:
                show_popup_rut()
            if ((validationRut(rut) == True) and (counter == '0') and (pass_in == pass_org)):
                return 10
            elif ((validationRut(rut) == True) and (counter == '1') and (pass_in == pass_org)):
                return 20 
        elif cell_one is None:
            show_popup_rut()
           
    def on_leave(self):
        self.input_rut_log.text = ""  
        self.input_pass.text = ""     

class ChangePasswordScreen(Screen):
    input_passRut= ObjectProperty()
    input_passNew= ObjectProperty()

    def on_pre_enter(self):
        Window.size = (350, 250)  

    def on_pre_enter(self):
        self.app = MDApp.get_running_app()

    def change_pass(self):
        passRut = self.input_passRut.text
        passNew = self.input_passNew.text

        @staticmethod
        def show_popup_invalid():
            popupWindow = Popup(title="¡invalid rut or password!", size_hint=(None,None),size=(200,50)) 
            popupWindow.open()
        @staticmethod
        def show_popup_passmatched():
            popupWindow = Popup(title="¡password change successful!", size_hint=(None,None),size=(300,50)) 
            popupWindow.open()
       
        passRut = re.sub("[^0-9]", "", passRut)
        cell_one = wks.find(passRut, in_column=1)
        if passRut == global_rut and cell_one is not None and len(passNew) > 5:
            wks.update_cell(cell_one.row, 4,'1')
            wks.update_cell(cell_one.row, 3, passNew)
            
            show_popup_passmatched()
            
            self.input_passRut.text = ""
            self.input_passNew.text = ""
            self.app.root.current = "login"
        elif passRut != global_rut or len(passNew) < 5:
            show_popup_invalid()

    def on_leave(self):
        self.input_passRut.text = ""  # Clear the text input
        self.input_passNew.text = ""  # Clear the text input 
  

class LiquidScreen(Screen):

    input_year = ObjectProperty()
    
    def on_press_download(self):
        @staticmethod
        def show_popup_invalid_year():
            popupWindow = Popup(title="Invalid year", size_hint=(None,None),size=(300,50)) 
            popupWindow.open()
            
        @staticmethod
        def show_popup_descarga():
            popupWindow = Popup(title="Download successful", size_hint=(None,None),size=(300,50)) 
            popupWindow.open()

        @staticmethod
        def login():
            gauth = GoogleAuth()
            gauth.LoadCredentialsFile(directory_credentials)

            if gauth.access_token_expired:
                gauth.Refresh()
                gauth.SaveCredentialsFile(directory_credentials)
            else:
                gauth.Authorize()
            return GoogleDrive(gauth)


        
        home_dir = Path.home()
        year = self.input_year.text
        rut = global_rut
        credentials = login()
        
        file_list_rut = credentials.ListFile({'q': "'{folder}' in parents".format(folder='1O3-gD9chTeCDIkUAYSj_E6MyjxWQzYrG')}).GetList()
        
        for f in file_list_rut:
            if f['title'] == rut:
                file_list_year = credentials.ListFile({'q': "'{folder}' in parents".format(folder=f['id'])}).GetList()
                for t in file_list_year:
                    if t['title'] == year:
                        file_list_liquid = credentials.ListFile({'q': "'{folder}' in parents".format(folder=t['id'])}).GetList()
                        for n in file_list_liquid:
                            fname = n['title']
                            f_ = credentials.CreateFile({'id': n['id']})
                            f_.GetContentFile(fname)
                        show_popup_descarga()
                    else:
                        show_popup_invalid_year()
            else:
                pass

        

    def on_leave(self):
        self.input_year.text = ""

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class LoginMillacheApp(MDApp):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    LoginMillacheApp().run()
```

and here's my kv file

```
WindowManager:
    id: scr_mngr
    LoginScreen:
    ChangePasswordScreen:
    LiquidScreen:


<LoginScreen>:
    id: log_1
    name: 'login'
    input_rut_log: input_rut_log
    input_pass: input_pass
    md_bg_color: 0, 1, 0, .5

    MDTextField:
        id: input_rut_log
        hint_text: "RUT"
        icon_right: 'email'
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .52, "center_y": .46}
        line_color_focus: 0, 0, 0, 1

    MDTextField:
        id: input_pass
        icon_right: 'key-variant'
        hint_text: "PASSWORD"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .52, "center_y": .32}
        line_color_focus: 0, 0, 0, 1
        password: True

    MDFlatButton:
        text: "Login"
        size_hint: .79, .08
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .20}
        on_press: 
            root_result = root.pass_on()
            if root_result == 10: root.manager.current = 'change_pass'
            elif root_result == 20: root.manager.current = 'liquid'
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: 41/255, 135/255, 168/255          
            RoundedRectangle:
                size: self.size 
                pos: self.pos
                radius: [6]


<ChangePasswordScreen>:
    name: 'change_pass'
    input_passRut: input_passRut
    input_passNew: input_passNew

    MDTextField:
        id: input_passRut
        hint_text: "  ENTER YOUR RUT"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .8}
        line_color_focus: 0, 0, 0, 1

    MDTextField:
        id: input_passNew
        hint_text: "  ENTER NEW PASS(6 CHAR MIN)"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .50}
        line_color_focus: 0, 0, 0, 1

    MDFlatButton:
        text: "CHANGE PASS"
        size_hint: .79, .08
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .20}
        on_release: root.change_pass()
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: 41/255, 135/255, 168/255          
            RoundedRectangle:
                size: self.size 
                pos: self.pos
                radius: [6]


<LiquidScreen>:
    name: 'liquid'

    input_year: input_year
    MDTextField:
        id: input_year
        hint_text: "  ENTER THE YEAR TO CHECK"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .8}
        line_color_focus: 0, 0, 0, 1

    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'DOWNLOAD'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
        on_release: root.on_press_download()

    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'CLOSE'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.3}
        on_release: app.stop()
```

at first in my output there were some missing modules, fix that and nothing, recursion error and also fix that, but now it does nothing, not even a warning or error, double click on my .exe or apk. and nothing